# iOS location authorization: dynamic content of NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering if there is a way to set the text for asking location authorization dynamically.  For example say depending on the device locale, US vs non-US, I want to be able to differentiate the text being displayed:

- Locale US -> set NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription = "ABC Text"
- Locale non-US -> set NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription = "XYZ Text"

UPDATE:
The language of the text itself will still be in the same language, like english, only the text content is different for US vs non-US.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to localize your app for the different locales.  This should generate separate copies of 'infoPlist.strings' which you can then update with:

```
"NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "ABC Text";
```

for one localization and

```
"NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "XYZ Text";
```

for the other.   You could see [Localizing Property List Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html) for more info.

Comment: Mark .. thank you for the response. I rephrased my question a bit. The locale is basically US vs non-US, not a language specific as usually created under like en.lproj or fr.lproj. The text language itself will still be in English but different text content.

Comment: I'm not aware of any method other than tweaking the infoPlist.strings files to control those but nothing says that for a resource file for fr.lproj for example, you have to put in French. It would be unusual but possible. You could create some localizations for the major languages (top-level) used by your app and update all of those with 'XYZ Text'. Same net effect.   If you just don't want to pay for translation services, there are probably good free ones out there.

Comment: @AndiSetiyadi You would need to set your base locale text to the non-us text and add a "translation" for en-us that had the us text but you should be aware that the device locale doesn't necessarily tell you anything about the device location, the citizenship of the user or the legal jurisdiction that applies.